# new relic and ruby: Can we use backticks expansion in a rails/newrelic config yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic

I'm using a modified version of

```
https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/master/newrelic.yml
```

in my rails config/ folder.

My license key is stored inside a binary. We usually retrieve it by giving the command

```
get_config new relic
```

Can I use backticks inside the new relic config file, to retrieve
the license key at rails boot time?

Comment: I think the config is processed by ERB (like the db config). Does using backticks inside ERB syntax work: ``<%= `get_config new relic` %>``?

Comment: According to the New Relic Ruby Agent configuration, it seems [environment variables](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/installation-configuration/ruby-agent-configuration#Options) are preferred.  You also might want to ask in the [Ruby Agent New Relic forum](https://discuss.newrelic.com/c/ruby-agent) for best-practice suggestions.